# How do I change which file is used for database configuration in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to use a different database.yml for each environment. How can I do this, either with an official API command, a monkeypatch, or some other hack?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ERB inside database.yml. So, you can use ERB to load configuration from other files and insert it to database.yml.

P.S.
  I recommend to use one database.yml because this is official way to specify database configuration.